# Scan nearby Wifi P2P services

Tags: android, wifip2p

So, I want to make an app that will start a Wifi P2P service and scan nearby available Wifi P2P services. This is how I will [create Wifi P2P service](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html#register).

But how do I scan nearby P2P services? There are 2 ways that claim to scan [this](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#discover) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html#discover). I don't understand the difference between two. I did try watching youtube videos but they were repeating the same thing. Pls, tell me which one to use to scan nearby P2P services created by other phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the method will scan nearby P2P devices. [this](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#discover) will show list of peers(devices) nearby whereas [this](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html#discover) is useful when you want to retrieve the "Map" that the other devices used when setting up `WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo`.